# Blazor server side docker container segmentation fault after adding second EF core database

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

So, I've been trying to get authentication into a blazor server side application. Getting the UI up and running went well, and the first issue came when trying to run the container in a cloud platform it could not decrypt, which then came down to the default storage of keys being such that they are lost after a container restart. So looking into that I felt like the easiest solution was just to add a second database, like it is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli#entity-framework-core). In the docs there it seemed fine with two dbcontexts, and I followed their code, with the two dbcontexts finally looking like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace AuthTest.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace AuthTest.Data
{
    public class AppKeyDbContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
    {
        public AppKeyDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppKeyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And ConfigureServices:

```
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("DataSource=app.db"));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    
    services.AddDbContext<AppKeyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("DataSource=key.db"));
    services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<AppKeyDbContext>();
```

Now building the container worked well at first with only one dbcontext, after adding the second one it first failed to add migrations and update database, which was a simple fix with adding --context flag to those commands. But after now having a container that builds fine, I end up with a .dll that crashes instantly due to a Segmentation Fault.

And Now I'm stumped. Since I got no errors with the dotnet ef commands for both contexts, and the dotnet build went through as well, I dont really know where to begin. And docker inspect / logs doesn't give any information from what I could find. And for what it's worth, the final dotnet .dll command is run in a mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, if anyone ends up with the same issue, that last line I wrote was actually worth quite a lot. Removing the "-alpine" part and going with the "normal" aspnet:5.0 for my runtime container proved to solve it for me in the end.